# Is it okay to experience pain right after a squat rep?

Tags: strength, squats, injury-prevention

I am 5'6", 146 pounds, and am doing a full-range barbell squat with weights totaling 165 pounds with the barbell. However, sometimes, I experience pain right after a rep in the upper parts of my thigh towards the inner side, which I am assuming is where the tendons attaching the upper part of the quads are located. This is not D.O.M.S. apparently, since it's right after a rep. Also it disappears within a second or two after I have stood up completely and have relaxed my legs. I usually get this pain during the latter sets-usually the 4th &/or 5th one (currently following the 5x5 program). Is this normal?

The even bigger problem is, the mental image of the tendons there tearing apart terrifies me during the latter reps, and this in fact ruins my focus and makes mistakes more prone to happen.

Edit: I would like to point out that I have added weights very gradually (about 5 pounds every two or three weeks, while squatting about 3 to 4 times a week, each time doing a 5x5 workout) so this cannot be because of a sudden increase in poundage; also this problem had existed with lower weights too, although it was less intense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we can't diagnose what causes one individual's pain. I would suggest getting with someone qualified to check your lifting form, and/or get it medically reviewed.

Comment: I do squat in front of the mirror. My right side has wider motion range, so I can't rely on simple feeling the motion. Without looking I tend to use my right side more. Other point - pelvis can be not leveled. There is simple exercise for that. Diagnose is one thing, but we should try to understand our bodies. If, from time to time, body says that something goes wrong, it it wise to ask. Doctor, or other trained person is best option. Over Internet it is really hard to help. However there are a lot of things you can do yourself - for good, or for bad.